# Sort main report by running total value for report with 4 groups

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

How can I sort my main report based on the value of a running total? This value is  for the `MIN(DATE)` within 4 groups. (Name, Location, Date, and Cost.)

Answer (score 0):

Reports have two phases: Reading and Printing. Data is assembled during the Read Phase, and everything else happens during the Print Phase. This means that a Running Total isn't evaluated until after the data is already assembled and sorted.

If you need the value of this Running Total *before* the Print Phase, I'd recommend writing a SQL statement to only return the minimum value for that combination of Name/Location/Date/Cost. That way all the useless records are filtered out during the Read Phase, and your report doesn't need to suppress anything.